# Get Average in dataframe column without using while loop

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find the sum of price data in a data frame.
My current code looks like this, whitch there must be a better way to do it

```
i=5
a = 0
while i<10
    a = a + df.loc[i]["Price"]
    i = i + 1
averg = a/5
print(averg)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note you should avoid chained indexing. It's ambiguous and [explicitly discouraged](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) in the docs, and instead you can use [`pd.DataFrame.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html). In addition, you can use the `+=` operator for incrementing a value. So you can rewrite as:

```
i = 5
a = 0
while i < 10
    a += df.at[i, 'Price']
    i += 1
avg = a/5
print(avg)
```

However, note you can use [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to combine row and index labelling and give a `pd.Series` object. You can then use [`pd.Series.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mean.html) to calculate the average:

```
avg = df.loc[5:10, 'Price'].mean()
```

This way you are also taking advantage of vectorised computations as opposed to using a Python-level loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using loops on dataframes is very inefficient. Try using vector calculations whenever possible. Pandas already has a function `mean()` for the same.
If the index of that column is "Price" then you could just do the following -
`df['Price'].mean()`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], columns=["Price", "Weight", "Size"])
>>> df
   Price  Weight  Size
0      1       2     3
1      4       5     6
2      7       8     9

>>> df.mean()
Price     4
Weight    5
Size      6
dtype: int64

>>> df["Price"].mean()
4
```